# Resizing SKSpriteNode with it's children

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I am trying to run a sequence of SKActions on a SKSpriteNode which has one child,
all the actions are performed on the 2 shapes together except :

```
[SKAction resizeToWidth:<#(CGFloat)#> height:<#(CGFloat)#> duration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>]
```

Here is my code:

```
-(void)CreateCards{
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *sprite=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"default_circle.png"];
    SKSpriteNode *shape=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[self GetRandomImage]];
    [sprite addChild:shape];
    sprite.position=CGPointMake(-43, 345);
    sprite.size=CGSizeMake(43, 43);
    shape.size=CGSizeMake(43, 43);


    SKAction *zoom=[SKAction group:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(60, 345) duration:0.75],[SKAction resizeToWidth:80 height:80 duration:0.75], nil]];
    zoom.timingMode=SKActionTimingEaseOut;

    SKAction *zoomOut=[SKAction group:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction moveTo:[self GetLocationOfIndex:i NumberOfCircles:3] duration:0.5],[SKAction resizeToWidth:43 height:43 duration:0.5], nil]];

    zoomOut.timingMode=SKActionTimingEaseIn;


    SKAction *enter=[SKAction sequence:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction waitForDuration:1*i],zoom,zoomOut, nil]];
    [sprite runAction:enter];


    [self addChild:sprite];
}
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve the desired effect you should use [scaling](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/scaleXBy:y:duration:) instead of resizing.

Replace:

```
SKAction *zoom=[SKAction group:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(60, 345) duration:0.75],[SKAction resizeToWidth:80 height:80 duration:0.75], nil]];
```

With:

```
SKAction *zoom=[SKAction group:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(60, 345) duration:0.75],[SKAction scaleXBy:80/43 y:80/43 duration:0.75], nil]];
```

Following code should work for your case:

```
-(void)CreateCards{
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *sprite=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"default_circle.png"];
    SKSpriteNode *shape=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[self GetRandomImage]];
    [sprite addChild:shape];
    sprite.position=CGPointMake(-43, 345);
    sprite.size=CGSizeMake(43, 43);
    shape.size=CGSizeMake(43, 43);

    CGFloat zoomScale = 80 / 43;
    SKAction *zoom=[SKAction group:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(60, 345) duration:0.75],[SKAction scaleXBy:zoomScale y:zoomScale duration:0.75], nil]];
    zoom.timingMode=SKActionTimingEaseOut;

    SKAction *zoomOut=[SKAction group:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction moveTo:[self GetLocationOfIndex:i NumberOfCircles:3] duration:0.5],[SKAction scaleXBy:1.0f y:1.0f duration:0.5], nil]];

    zoomOut.timingMode=SKActionTimingEaseIn;


    SKAction *enter=[SKAction sequence:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction waitForDuration:1*i],zoom,zoomOut, nil]];
    [sprite runAction:enter];


    [self addChild:sprite];
}
}
```

Comment: No problem :). Also some syntax sugar, you can use @[...] instead of [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...,nil]. ;)